# Java bukkit config file for player homes not allowing teleportation

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a config file `Homes.yml` that  I am using to the store home of users on a server to be able to teleport to between reloads.  Currently the `/ksethome` command is working and the config file is updated with the proper coordinates.

However, when executing the `/khome` command an error is thrown.

Here is a copy of `Homes.yml`

```
Homes:
  Kalenpw:
    ==: org.bukkit.Location
    yaw: 174.53154
    pitch: 18.115198
    z: 89.15419690166142
    y: 100.0
    world: Khalidor
    x: 99.43791494211929
```

and here is a copy of the plugin

```
//@kalenpw

package com.Khalidor.testplugin;

import java.util.HashMap;    
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.PlayerInventory;

public final class TestPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    MyConfigManager manager;
    MyConfig homesConfig;
    HashMap<String, Location> playerHomes = new HashMap<String, Location>();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {

        getLogger().info("onEable has been invoked!");
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        manager = new MyConfigManager(this);
        homesConfig = manager.getNewConfig("Homes.yml");

        // TODO add stuff to hashmap onEnable()

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // when plugin is disabled
        getLogger().info("onDisable has been invoked");


    }




    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player user = (Player) sender;

            // Sethome
            if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("KSetHome")) {

                playerHomes.put(user.getName(), user.getLocation());
                homesConfig.set("Homes." + user.getName(), user.getLocation());
                homesConfig.saveConfig();
                user.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Set home!");

            }
            // TP home
            if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("KHome")) {

                // Location homeLocation = playerHomes.get(user.getName());
                /*
                 * Location homeLocation = homesConfig.get("Homes." +
                 * user.getName(), );
                 */
                String worldName = homesConfig.getString("Homes." + user.getName() + ".world");
                World homeWorld = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(worldName);
                double homeX = homesConfig.getDouble("Homes." + user.getName() + ".x");
                double homeY = homesConfig.getDouble("Homes." + user.getName() + ".y");
                double homeZ = homesConfig.getDouble("Homes." + user.getName() + ".z");
                Location homeLocation = new Location(homeWorld, homeX, homeY, homeZ);
                user.teleport(homeLocation);
                user.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Teleported home!");

            }
            return true;
        }
        // Not executed by player
        return false;

    }

}
```

finally, a copy of the error:

```
[21:25:01 INFO]: Kalenpw issued server command: /ksethome
[21:25:04 INFO]: Kalenpw issued server command: /khome
[21:25:04 ERROR]: null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'khome' in plugin TestPlugin v1.0
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) ~[spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:645) ~[spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1350) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1185) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:45) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:1) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [?:1.7.0_85]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [?:1.7.0_85]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:45) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:721) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:400) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:660) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_9_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:559) [spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_85]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null
        at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192) ~[spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_9_R1.CraftServer.getWorld(CraftServer.java:1022) ~[spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        at com.Khalidor.testplugin.TestPlugin.onCommand(TestPlugin.java:152) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[spigot-1.9.2.jar:git-Spigot-5a40365-b70058a]
        ... 15 more
```

I've done a bit of googling around and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. From what I can tell I'm creating the Location object wrong from the Homes.yml because I can switch the code to just use a hashmap and it works fine which also eliminates the plugin.yml as being the issue.  Thanks for the help!

Edit:

Line 152 from TestPlugin.java

```
World homeWorld = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(worldName);
```

Edit:

Apparently the issue is every way I've gone about getting my world is returning null. I used `Bukkit.broadcastMessage(Bukkit.getWorlds().toString());` to check to make sure that I was using the proper string to get the world from and that broadcasted  `[CraftWorld{name=Khalidor}, CraftWorld{name=Khalidor_nether}, CraftWorld{name=Khalidor_the_end}]` I'm not in the Nether or End So it appears to me it should be picking up that world.

When I run these `String worldName = homesConfig.getString("Homes." + user.getName() + ".world");
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(worldName);`

I get a null pointer exception so for whatever reason I'm getting null back instead of the name of my world. Still figuring out why that is going on.

Edit:

So I've figured out the issue is with my YML file instead of using the String from Homes.yml I just entered the string of my world and now it reads the X Y Z locations all as 0 so for some reason it's reading that wrong.

Edit: solved turns out the issue wasn't in the YML file but I had a line of code left in from earlier testing that was causing issues with the YML because I was saving the x y z and then overwriting with a location.

Comment: TestPlugin.java line 152 ... what is it?

Comment: @cricket_007 World homeWorld = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(worldName);

Comment: And does "IllegalArgumentException: Name cannot be null" mean anything to you?

Comment: @cricket_007 not entirely sure what that means no, but I'm guessing it isn't finding the world

Comment: It would appear `homesConfig.getString("Homes." + user.getName() + ".world");` has returned null. Probably because that string was not found in your config. You may print out `worldName` on the following line to check

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah you're correct when I print the worldName to console nothing appears

Comment: @cricket_007 would you happen to know why it can't find anything in my config file? I still can't figure that out

Comment: Not sure, sorry. Never used bukkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check to see if "homesConfig.contains("Homes." + user.getName() + )" before you try to use it. I think getting something that the config file doesn't contain will just return null.

 Here's how you could check it

```
if (!homesConfig.contains("Homes." + user.getName() + ".world") || <just copy the first condition but for the different elements, like x, y, z, ect>) {
    user.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "No home set");
    return true;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it could work. Also pogostick29dev has a lot of bukkit tutorials, one covers settings managers, if you wanted to check him out.

Comment: That's a good idea I'll implement that. They do return null if nothing is there that's what is going on that it won't allow me to tp players the World returns null and the x y z all return 0. Any idea how to fix that? My syntax appears to be correct based off the AppleJuze tutorials I've been watching

Comment: X y and z probably return 0 because they're ints and not objects, so they can't be null, it's just setting them to the closest thing to null they can be.

Comment: Yeah I got that couldn't figure out why they were not found in the file though. I ended up having some old line of code when I was just saving the location to Homes.yml which was messing with it after deleting that the tp works fine. I'll accept your answer cause while implementing the check if a home is set is when I noticed the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Not tested)

In line 152:

```
String worldName = homesConfig.getString("Homes." + user.getName() + ".world");
```

should be

```
World homeWorld = ((Location) getConfig().get("Homes." + user.getName())).getWorld();
```

Why?

You store the Location in line

> homesConfig.set("Homes." + user.getName(), **user.getLocation()**);

So you have to retrieve the Location. You then can get the World of that Location.

Also, you should not use the names of the players, since you can change your name on mojangs website. Use the UID of Player instead.

Comment: Good point on the UUIDs I hadn't thought of that. However after changing line 152 I still get a  null pointer exception Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.Khalidor.testplugin.TestPlugin.onCommand(TestPlugin.java:151) ~[?:?]

note: I delted a line so 151 is still the line in question here